Solving $\frac{M e^{-M}}{1-e^{-1}} - \epsilon = 0$ for $M \in \mathbb{R}$
I am trying to solve the following nonlinear equation analytically:
$$
\frac{M e^{-M}}{1-e^{-1}}  - \epsilon = 0 \, ,
$$
where $ M \in \mathbb{R} $ and $ 0 < \epsilon \ll 1 $.
A solution can be expressed using the LambertW / ProductLog function as:
$$
M = -W\left( \epsilon (e^{-1}-1) \right) \, .
$$
For $\epsilon = 10^{-6} $, one finds approximately $ M \approx 6.32 \times 10^{-7} $.
However, I am more interested in the solution where $ M \approx 17.11 $ using these numerical values. I am wondering whether an analytical formula can likewise be obtained for this latter case.

You are  then concerned by the second branch of Lambert function
$$M=-W_{-1}\left(-\frac{e-1 }{e}\,\,\epsilon \right)$$
Let $x=-\frac{e-1 }{e}\,\,\epsilon$ and use the expansion
given here.
If you let $\epsilon=10^{-k}$, $M$ is quite close to be a linear function of $k$ as you could show using the formula.

Brilliant. Thanks a lot.

In the case of $M=25.61$, we have that
$$\epsilon \approx \frac{1.9}{10^{10}(1-x)}$$
and equivalently that
$$x\approx1-\frac{1.9}{10^{10} \epsilon}$$
by simply algebra. So, setting $x=0.5$, one finds $\epsilon \approx 3.9 \times 10^{-10}$. The answer is so simple that I'm not sure if it is actually what you are asking, but these indeed are the analytical solutions for $x, \epsilon$ given $M \approx 25.61$.

Thanks. Nope. I need a general solution for arbitrary $\epsilon$ and $x$. The numerical example simply serves to show the existence of the solution of interest.

This gives you the curve of possible $(x,\epsilon)$ for any choice of value for $M$.

I am sorry. There should be no $x$. I have already set $x = e^{-1}$.

The "unknown" is not $M$, since you are asking to analyze the case for specific values of $M$. Setting $x=1/e$ will still work in my above formulae. Also, in your question you already solved for $M$ in terms of $(x,\epsilon)$.

I have reformulated the question now. There is no $x$

Did you miss where I wrote you can simply plug in $x=1/e$ into the formulae?
